# Default number of connections that are allowed per ip per minute/second

Tags: iptables, ip-conntrack

I have the following rules applied as a part of DDoS prevention.

To prevent Spoofed packets

```
-A INPUT -s 255.0.0.0/8 -j LOG --log-prefix "Spoofed source IP"
-A INPUT -s 255.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 0.0.0.0/8 -j LOG --log-prefix "Spoofed source IP"
-A INPUT -s 0.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```

To prevent Stealth scan and TCP SYN flood

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "Stealth scan attempt?"
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

Now we want to enforce no of connections that are allowed per IP Address per minute . For that I was planning to use `--limit` extensions. But looks now it is recommended to use `--cstate` extension. Few queries..

1. What is the default no of connections that are allowed per ip address per minute/second with iptables.
2. Default no of connections per minute/second? Any such limitation at OS level
3. Suppose I want to allow 60 connections per second and if it goes beyond that limit, I will enforce to 25 connections per second. For this below rule is fine

   ```
   /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 25/s --limit-burst 60 -j ACCEPT
   /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
   ```

Is the second rule necessary after adding the first rule.